# SubscribableJmsChannel bug?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, activemq-artemis

In the onMessage event, if the message does not get converted as a Spring Integration message it will try and use the MessageBuilder to rebuild it.  But it doesn't include the headers.  This seems incorrect.  We're using Apache Artemis 1.2 and Spring 4.2.5.

Here is the code in question from `SubscribableJmsChannel`:

```
public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message message) {
    Message<?> messageToSend = null;
    try {
        Object converted = this.jmsTemplate.getMessageConverter().fromMessage(message);
        if (converted != null) {
            messageToSend = (converted instanceof Message<?>) ? (Message<?>) converted
                    : this.messageBuilderFactory.withPayload(converted).build();
            this.dispatcher.dispatch(messageToSend);
        }
        else if (this.logger.isWarnEnabled()) {
            logger.warn("MessageConverter returned null, no Message to dispatch");
        }
    }
```

Sometimes we see messages get converted as Spring messages and sometimes they are attempted to be converted from the Spring message payload (1 in 20 times or so).  In that case, the below code seems to try and handle recreating the Spring message envelope - but it will drop the headers.

What's interesting is that our code is always sending the exact same message in a load test.  I haven't figured out why the messages would be received differently yet.

Comment: ??? You should share the config/code on the matter. Or even better test-case to reproduce from our side. Otherwise it looks like a bad question and will be considered for closing.

Comment: Thanks, I can put together a sample if necessary - it just seems the Spring code is wrong.  It's causing an issue as we store some items in the header and they are lost.

Comment: Yes, that would be great if you'd share some simple test-case to play from our side.